# Mongodb - TypeError: ReplSetServers is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, node-mongodb-native, mongodb-replica-set

I'm developing an app, which has mongodb as database. I'm using multiple URLs to connect mongodb. I have used following to connect DB.

```
var mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Db = require('mongodb').Db;
var Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var ReplSetServers = require('mongodb').ReplSetServers;

var replSet = new ReplSetServers([
   new Server('localhost', 30000),
   new Server('localhost', 30001),
   new Server('localhost', 30002)
]);

var db = new Db('machaao', replSet, {w:0});
```

[Reference Link](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html)

After importing package by using `require` I didn't get any error. But after using `new ReplSetServers` I got the following error. `TypeError: ReplSetServers is not a function`.

Are there any dependency packages that I have to import? or should I make changes in code? I have no idea why that error comes. And I haven't found any related answer on Google.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `ReplSetServers` referred to in the error `TypeError: ReplSetServers is not a function` refers to the last line.

```
var db = new Db('machaao', ReplSetServers, {w:0});
```

should be

```
var db = new Db('machaao', replSet, {w:0});`
```

Comment: When I console the mongodb package, I couldn't see ReplSetServers in that package.